# Fail to get retweets with R and Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter

I'd like to track the path in which a tweet below was retweeted, which seems not supported by the twitteR package yet. Therefore I tried with packages RCurl and RJSONIO, but failed. Below is what I did.

Tweet id 333572281450258432, "Introduction to Data Science, a free online course on Coursera already started on May 1st ..."

- OS: MAX OS X 10.6.8,
- Software: R v3.0.0,
- R packages: twitteR v1.1.6, ROAuth v0.9.3, RCurl v1.95-4.1, RJSONIO
  v1.0-3

  > library(twitteR)
  >
  > library(ROAuth)
  >
  > library(RCurl)
  >
  > library(RJSONIO)

Authentication with Twitter has been successful.

```
> cred <- OAuthFactory$new(...)

> cred$handshake()

> registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

 TRUE
```

The code below worked and returned a list of users who have retweeted the above tweet 333572281450258432.

```
> url <- "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/333572281450258432/retweeted_by.json"

> rt.list <- fromJSON(httpGET(url))
```

Then I tried to get the retweets id with code below, but failed.

```
> url <- "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets/333572281450258432.json"

> retweets.list <- fromJSON(httpGET(url))
  error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error: Bad Request
```

When trying the above url in browser, it showed

{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

The above used Twitter API v1. And I also tried Twitter API v1.1 with code below, which failed with errors same as above. The reason for the failure of the two queries below could be that I haven't set up authentication corrently with Twitter API v1.1.

```
> url <- "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/333572281450258432.json"

> url <- "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweeters/ids.json?id=333572281450258432&count=100&stringify_ids=true"
```

Anybody has experience on this and can help on

- retrieving retweets of a tweet with R, or
- set up authentication with Twitter API v1.1 under R?

Thanks. 
Yanchang Zhao.
[RDataMining.com](http://www.rdatamining.com)